# How to set expiration date in Android

Tags: android, android-calendar

I have an Android App and I want to give it for testing purpose, after the expiration date the app has to show a dialog and block the commands.

here my code to show dialog and block command

```
public void expired(){
    bt1.setEnabled(false)
    bt2.setEnabled(false)
    bt3.setEnabled(false)
    bt4.setEnabled(false)
    bt5.setEnabled(false)
Alerts.AppExpiredMessage(Home.this);
}
```

but How to set expiration date in Android in the form

```
if(appLicenseExpired){
void expired();
}
```

verifying that the actual date is antecedent a set expiration date(for example 3rd March 2013)??

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following sets `isExpired` as of 12/31/2014:

```
GregorianCalendar expDate = new GregorianCalendar( 2013, 11, 31 ); // midnight
GregorianCalendar now = new GregorianCalendar();

boolean isExpired = now.after( expDate );
```

Note: Months are 0-based. January = 0, December = 11.

Comment: For testing purposes, you can instantiate `GregorianCalendar( 2013, 2, 14, 21, 20 );` (Central Time, US, expires in five minutes -- adjust for your own timezone)

Comment: I have tested your code changing the phone date, but for some reason works a month after, If I set expiation date ( 2013, 3, 29 ) the app expires after the 29th April 2013. Any solutions? Thanks

Comment: Whoops, I keep forgetting that -- Months are 0-based, see edit to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, there is no method that is 100% guaranteed to prevent hacking because an experienced programmer with a rooted phone can pretty much do anything (including decompiling your app and hack it)

The easiest way is to make the expiration date a fixed date which you can simply hard code it in your app.

If you want to make the app expires after certain period from the installation time (say 30 days), just on the first get the phone identifier (e.g. IMEI) and/or android account (e.g. email) then store it to a server with the installation date. You can store the installation date also on the phone (e.g. SharedPreference) so you can check on every run without going to the server.

**Edit**

The simplest way to check for the expiry date is to use `System.currentTimeMillis()` to avoid dealing with TimeZone. You can use online service such as [Epoch Time Converter](http://www.esqsoft.com/javascript_examples/date-to-epoch.htm), to know the `epoch` value for the expiry date and just check it in your code

```
if(System.currentTimeMillis() >= EXPIRY_EPOCH){

}
```

Comment: I want only a simply way that verifying that the actual date is antecedent a set expiration date... isn't important IMEI. Because I have to give a sample app for review and I want that expire after a precise date (for example after 3rd March 2013)

Comment: @AndreaF Either hardcoding the expiration date or storing the installation date as a SharedPreference should work then.

Comment: @Code-Guru
The problem is that I haven't experience with the calendar management and I don't know how compare and set a precise date in the code.

Comment: @AndreaF Check out the GregorianCalendar and Date classes.